# Validation to fill all textfield or None

Tags: jquery, html

I have a 5 text fields they are Billing Address,City,State, PostalCode,Country here I want to validate these fields in such way that if the user fills any one of the textfield he must fill all of them for example if a user enter city field he must enter all the fields i.e Billing Address,State,postal code or if he enters Address he must enter all the fields i.e City,State,postal code an so on or else he must not enter any of the fields.

As I have written this code but from this i am not getting exact results it will only works when i start enter serially i.e first address and then city and then state so on and also the message is displayed as many times i click submit button It is not displaying once can any one please look at this code and make necessary changes.Thanks in advance for this help.

```js
$('#SAVE_HEADER').click(function() {
  var valid = true;
  var requiredFields = ['billing_address_street', 'billing_address_city', 'billing_address_state', 'billing_address_postalcode', 'billing_address_country'];
  for (var i = 0; i < requiredFields.length; i++) {
    var val = $('#' + requiredFields[i]);
    if (val.val() == '') {
      var b = i;
      var a = requiredFields.length - b;

      if (b != 0 && a != 5)
        $("<span>Enter all the Address Fileds!</span>").appendTo('#billing_address_fieldset');

    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="billing_address_fieldset">
  <legend>Billing Address1</legend>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="edit" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="billing_address_street_label" width="%" scope="row">
          <label for="billing_address_street">Billing Address1:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="billing_address_street" name="billing_address_street" maxlength="150" rows="2" cols="30" tabindex="0"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="billing_address_city_label" width="%" scope="row">
          <label for="billing_address_city">Billing City:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="billing_address_city" id="billing_address_city" size="30" maxlength="100" value="" tabindex="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="billing_address_state_label" width="%" scope="row">
          <label for="billing_address_state">Billing State:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="billing_address_state" id="billing_address_state" size="30" maxlength="100" value="" tabindex="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="billing_address_postalcode_label" width="%" scope="row">
          <label for="billing_address_postalcode">Billing Postal Code:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="billing_address_postalcode" id="billing_address_postalcode" size="30" maxlength="20" value="" tabindex="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="billing_address_country_label" width="%" scope="row">
          <label for="billing_address_country">Billing Country:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="billing_address_country" id="billing_address_country" size="30" maxlength="150" value="" tabindex="0">
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" nowrap="">
            <input type="submit" id="SAVE_HEADER">
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: could you consider to put code in stackoverflow in addition to the jsfiddle please? Thanks

Comment: A jsfiddle link is nice but put your code to, so people can read and learn.

Comment: @vinayak did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I re-write your script, welle formatted and in your own style! Your script was a bit messy :-)

```
$('#SAVE_HEADER').click(function() {
    var dataInForm = false;
    var allFieldsFilled = true;

    var requiredFields = ['billing_address_street', 'billing_address_city', 'billing_address_state', 'billing_address_postalcode', 'billing_address_country'];

    // Know if there are data in form
    for (var i = 0; i < requiredFields.length; i++) {
        var val = $('#' + requiredFields[i]);
        if (val.val() != '' && !dataInForm) {
            // there are data in form so put true
            dataInForm = true;
        }
    }

    // If there is data in form, loop tu search empty fields
    if (dataInForm) {
        for (var ii = 0; ii < requiredFields.length; ii++) {
            var val2 = $('#' + requiredFields[ii]);
            if (val2.val() !== '' && allFieldsFilled) {
                allFieldsFilled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // put message if there is at least 1 data in form && fields are missing
    if (dataInForm && !allFieldsFilled) {
        $('#errorplaceholder').html("<span>Enter all the Address Fileds!</span>");
    }
});
```

You just have to add div with errorplaceholder id:

```
<div id="errorplaceholder"></div>
```

You can also tets it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/1jzybq9n/7/

**EDIT:**

You don't have accesss to the HTML rendered, so just add the div in jquery and then use it in the onclick. For this, just add this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      // Add div placeholder for error managment
    $("<div id=\"errorplaceholder\"></div>").appendTo('fieldset');
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/1jzybq9n/9/

**EDIT**

here is your final version

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      // Add div placeholder for error managment
    $("<div id=\"errorplaceholder\"></div>").appendTo('fieldset');
});

$('#SAVE_HEADER').click(function() {  
    var dataInForm = false;
    var allFieldsFilled = true;

    var requiredFields = ['billing_address_street', 'billing_address_city', 'billing_address_state', 'billing_address_postalcode', 'billing_address_country'];

    // Know if there are data in form
    for (var i = 0; i < requiredFields.length; i++) {
        var val = $('#' + requiredFields[i]);
        if (val.val() != '' && !dataInForm) {
            // there are data in form so put true
            dataInForm = true;
        }
    }

    // If there is data in form, loop tu search empty fields
    if (dataInForm) {
        for (var ii = 0; ii < requiredFields.length; ii++) {
            var val2 = $('#' + requiredFields[ii]);
            if ( (val2.val().length == 0) && allFieldsFilled) {
                allFieldsFilled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // put message if there is at least 1 data in form && fields are missing
    if (dataInForm && !allFieldsFilled) {
        $('#errorplaceholder').html("<span>Enter all the Address Fileds!</span>");
    }
    else {
        if(dataInForm && allFieldsFilled)
        {
            $('#errorplaceholder').html("");
        }
    }
});
```

With fiddle too : http://jsfiddle.net/1jzybq9n/10/

Comment: Thanks friend it worked fine but one thing is that as many times I am clicking the submit button that many times the message is displaying. Because I am not able to create html div because it is dynamic html file I should include the span in jquery code. and also after filling all the fields the message is not disappearing.Once again I am very much thankful for this help

Comment: OK so let me create the div in jQuery and then use it as my script do (only one message on the page). See my edited answer @vinayak

Comment: Ya nice!!!! thanks It worked. only one thing if all fields are filled when I click on submit the message is not disappearing.

Comment: Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/1jzybq9n/10/ but I think code is clean enough to make the latest edit alone... whatever I did it for you @vinayaktanksali

Comment: Thank u very much it worked fantastic once again thanku very very much

Comment: @vinayaktanksali : You're welcome! Please consider to validate the respone by pressing the "V" on the top of my answer!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine. Try moving the js code before body tag ends. It works.